# How to use psycopg2 module using Mac

Tags: python, macos, installation

I am trying to import psycopg2 in a python file I created to establish a connection with my Postgres database. Issue is that my system shows I have psycopg2 installed when I run the following in my terminal `pip freeze | grep psycopg2` but in my `.py` file I have the following code

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=test user=postgres')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM my_data")
records = cur.fetchall()
```

and it fails at the import. The problem I get is `Import "psycopg2" count not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource)`

What am I doing wrong. I have `psycopg2-binary` installed as well. My Mac version is `Big Sur version 11.6`

My `psycopg2` version is `2.8.6`

Comment: Does the script still work? That looks like an IDE misconfiguration (maybe your IDE isn't looking at the right Python interpreter).

Comment: Omg, you are right but one thing that I can't get working is that for some reason my code is running fine when I run it using `python my_file.py` but if I try running it using `python3 my_file.py` it does not work

Comment: Now that I know it is using my python2 interpreter how can I make it so that I can use it with python3

Comment: I don't know which IDE you're using.